# concat Buffer of response body not writing on file, and even shows on console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I've tried to test a req/res using node.js and fs to write a input to file using that code bellow.

I tried to use a `console.log()` but nothing shows refering the parsed body (data concated). Only the chunks is showed on terminal output.

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const url = req.url;
    const method = req.method;
    if (url === '/') {
        res.write('<html>');
        res.write('<head><title>Enter a Message</title></head>');
        res.write('<body><form action="/message" method="POST"><input type="text" name="message"><button type="submit">Send</button></form></body>');
        res.write('</html>');
        return res.end();
    }
    if (url === '/message' && method === 'POST') {
        const body = [];
        req.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log(chunk);
            body.push(chunk);
        });
        req.on('end', () => {
            const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
            const message = parsedBody.split('=')[1];
            fs.writeFileSync('message.txt', message);


            console.log(parsedBody); // dont shows on terminal output
        });
        res.statusCode = 302;
        res.setHeader('Location', '/');
        return res.end();
    }

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write('<html>');
    ...
    res.write('</html>');
    res.end();
});

Whats the problem I did to get it? I believe I am  doing something wrong, but what?

thanks in advice.
```

Comment: Just a thought: Try to remove the last `res.end()` right after `res.write('</html>')` and see if the socket is closed before the last chunk is received

Comment: by removig do not work, but adding return before it works fie. Thanks you

Comment: Do you see that you're doing res.end() twice? Once after receiving the last chunk and at the end of the request handler. This one will be called before the last chunk is received. I am pretty sure that's what gives you trouble. Perhaps use `if-else` for the different requests?

Comment: I got it, I will use check as you said. thanks